# SQL injection: mechanism

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection

Many answers on SO talk about the SQL injection and remedies against it, which is clear to me. What most of them don't touch (or perhaps I don't get it) is how actually a malicious SQL gets injected into the query.

Here is my confusion.

Suppose an example: php + pdo (or mysqli) + Mysql. The code:

`$sql = "select SomeName from SomeTable where SomeNameId = $neededId";`
`$pdoInstance->query($sql);`

If I understand right, to append some malicious code to the `$neededId` variable, an attacker needs to know about the existence of the `$neededId` variable. But to find out the variable name, an attacker has to surpass the php interpreter which I don't think is easy.

Could someone clarify?

Comment: In case you create $neededId inside the code - there is no problem. But often neededId comes from request, then hacker can put malicious code to that variable.

Comment: Consider the query `SELECT user.username FROM user WHERE user.username = '{$_POST['user']}'` ... then all the attacker need do is enter their username as something like `' OR 1=1; --`

Comment: The idea normally is that you fill in "$neededId" from some input-field on the page. And then this content is put into your query-string. The attacker does not need to know the variable name for that. He just uses the input field where you expect the username. You get the username from that field and write it to the var. The var is put into the querystring. then you execute the query...

Comment: How is `$neededId` assigned in this code example? There are second level injections where the malicious data is already in your DB, and you access it trusting that (which you shouldn't do), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Second_order_SQL_injection.

Comment: @dingalapadum, now i get it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @chris85, it comes from the form input. i guess the 2nd order sql injection is the next thing to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, an attacker must maybe guess the name of a table.
for example:

```
$neededId = "0; DELETE FROM tblUser;"

select SomeName from SomeTable where SomeNameId = $neededId
```

If that doesn't work, try the next tablename: tblCustomer, tblcontact, etc, etc.

You just don't want that to be possible.

Edit: In case you are building some famous open sourced framework, people don't even have to guess the tablenames, they can look them up.

**OP asked: "how an attacker can inject delete blah-blah from tblUser into the $neededId variable?"**

That is very easy. Your data comes in from a form. A HTML form. You can put ANYTHING inside the post. It cannot be trusted.

You can do it by building your own HTML form, or use it on the webpage itself, eg via:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/

Does that answer your inquiry?

Comment: thanks erwin. i was asking a bit different thing (i guess that wasn't clear from my post). :-) how an attacker can inject `delete blah-blah from tblUser` into the `$neededId` variable? if you modify your answer please keep what you wrote because i didn't know about that.

Comment: @DimaDz if this select is part of a login system, the attacker don't need to execute a delete query: he log in as administrator and use the standard user management in backoffice in order to delete anything he wants. hint: there's always a way

Comment: @chumkiu How can an attacker know the credentials to log in as admin?

Comment: @ErwinMoller I said: if this select is a part of a login system

Comment: @chumkiu Yes, I read that the first time correctly. I just do not understand what it is you are saying and how it does relate to SQL Injection.

Comment: @ErwinMoller is not related to your answer but to the comment of Dima. Simply we should not "relax" because the injection is "only" inside a select (not always is possible to do a multi-query, so not always your injection works). that's all

Comment: @chumkiu Aaah, I see now what you mean. :-) Sorry I was so slow to pick that up!